# "Use mysqli or PDO" error

Tags: php, pdo, mysqli

I'm getting an error telling me to use mysqli or PDO while i run the code below. Please help me to change it into `mysqli` code. I tried but it did not work as I am a beginner and I copied this code.

```
<?php

//Make the database connection.
db_connect() or die('Unable to connect to database server!');

function db_connect($server = 'localhost', $username = 'root', $password = '', $database =    'hct_db', $link = 'db_link') {
global $$link;
$$link = mysql_connect($server, $username, $password);
if ($$link) mysql_select_db($database);
return $$link;
}

//Function to handle database errors.
 function db_error($query, $errno, $error) { 
 die('Cannot connect to database');
 }

//Function to query the database.
function db_query($query, $link = 'db_link') {
global $$link;
$result = mysql_query($query, $$link) or db_error($query, mysql_errno(), mysql_error());
return $result;
}

//Get a row from the database query
function db_fetch_array($db_query) {
return mysql_fetch_array($db_query, MYSQL_ASSOC);
}
?>
```

Comment: what error you are getting?

Comment: Deprecated: mysql_connect(): The mysql extension is deprecated and will be removed in the future: use mysqli or PDO. dont give me - point plz

Comment: the code you use is deprecated. That is reason why you are getting error. Error is explaining it self.

Comment: are you asking for a `mysqli` or `PDO` example?

Comment: no, can you change it in mysqli ?

Comment: no, can you change it in mysqli ?

Comment: `mysqli` uses a different library of functions which arnt compatible with `mysql` so by changing over to `mysqli` a lot of your code will also need to be rewritten

Comment: Huh? You copy-pasted an example and realised it's wrong? Just copy a different example.

Comment: rjdown this is what i need and its not wrong.

Comment: What an awfull hack is that.. `$$link` o_O

Comment: stop giving me negative points all the time :( -_-

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL extension is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and is not recommended for writing new code as it will be removed in the future. Instead, either the mysqli or PDO_MySQL extension should be used.

As quick solution with MySQLi

```
<?php

//Make the database connection.
db_connect() or die('Unable to connect to database server!');

function db_connect($server = 'localhost', $username = 'root', $password = '', $database =    'hct_db', $link = 'db_link') {
    global $$link;
    $$link = mysqli_connect($server, $username, $password);
    if ($$link) mysqli_select_db($$link, $database);
    return $$link;
}

//Function to handle database errors.
function db_error($query, $errno, $error) { 
    die('Cannot connect to database');
}

//Function to query the database.
function db_query($query, $link = 'db_link') {
    global $$link;
    $result = mysqli_query($$link, $query) or db_error($query, mysqli_errno($$link), mysqli_error($$link));
    return $result;
}

//Get a row from the database query
function db_fetch_array($db_query) {
    return mysqli_fetch_array($db_query);
}
?>
```

Comment: @AakkiRock Please let me know if you need further help. Please vote up my answer if you found it useful.

Comment: everyone voting down whenever i asked a question :/ need 15 reputation to vote up though i accepted your solution :)